# Reduce the merge audio file?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I merge the two audio files in Swift2.3.

It's working fine. The file size is 7MB. So I am not able to send to the server.

How to reduce the audio file size? So that I can easily send to the server.
I attached the code below. It will be useful for those who are trying to merge:

```
 func mixAudio()
{
    let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack.preferredVolume = 0.8
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL, options: nil)
    print("\(avAsset)")
    var tracks = avAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack = tracks[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    let compositionAudioTrack1 = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    compositionAudioTrack.preferredVolume = 0.8

    let avAsset1 = AVURLAsset.init(URL: soundFileURL1)
    print(avAsset1)


    var tracks1 = avAsset1.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
    let clipAudioTrack1 = tracks1[0]
    do {
        try compositionAudioTrack1.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration), ofTrack: clipAudioTrack1, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let CachesDirectory = paths[0]
    let strOutputFilePath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/newone.mov")
    print(" strOutputFilePath is \n \(strOutputFilePath)")

    let requiredOutputPath = CachesDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/newone.m4a")
    print(" requiredOutputPath is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")

    let audioFileOutput = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(requiredOutputPath)
    print(" OUtput path is \n \(audioFileOutput)")
    do {

        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(audioFileOutput)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    exporter!.outputURL = audioFileOutput
    exporter!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A

    exporter!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler
        {() -> Void in
            print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")
            print("export complete: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - currentTime)")

    do
    {
        print(audioFileOutput)
        print(" OUtput path is \n \(requiredOutputPath)")

        self.wasteplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileOutput)
        self.wasteplayer.numberOfLoops = 0
        self.wasteplayer.play()

        }
    }

    catch _
    {

    }

    }
```

Comment: Encode to MP3 or AAC after merging?

Comment: Iam not encode anything..I just merge the two audio file(One file is background song()mp3 and another one is voice(m4a) i recorded already).i attached the code above..i just check the merged file in folder..the size should be 7MB.soi want to reduce the size.

Comment: And that is why I'm suggesting you to encode your audio to MP3 or AAC **after** merging...

Comment: ohhh..okok.. do you have any sample or idea for encode in mp3? I don't idea about to encrypt audio to MP3 or AAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be providing a audio setting dictionary to your writer.
Here are the following formats you can look into

kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC : 164, (Lowest)

kAudioFormatAppleLossless : 430,

kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 : 475,

kAudioFormatULaw : 889,

kAudioFormatALaw : 889

Use kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC It is smallest among all.

```
       let audioOutputSettings = [
            AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey :     //[ NSNumber numberWithInt: 16 ], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                Int(44100.0),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : Int(1),
            AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)),
 ]
```

This is the above setting in Swift.

At this line

let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

Can u try this instead

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality)
```

Comment: My bad, your code was not loaded in my browser, Now it does any ways yes I am giving it a try

Comment: I have edited the answer, and you can try to do the change I have mentioned in the last line.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37266/discussion-between-grzegorz-krukowski-and-newbie

May be a reference

Comment: Thankyou, I will try that and let you know

Comment: I tried this,But it display error in fileType                                                    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality)
        exporter!.outputURL = audioFileOutput
        exporter!.outputFileType = AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality

Comment: I guess you got the error because that particular preset is only for video I guess.